# How do I display this quadric (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) in maple?

Tags: maple, quadrics

$x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz-x-y-z=6$

I'm struggling to draw a quadric in maple. I've tried the plot and plot3d functions, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the *implicitplot3d* command in the *plots* package.

```
with(plots):
implicitplot3d(x^2+y^2+z^2+2*x*y+2*x*y+2*y*z-x-y-z=6, x=-10..10, y=-10..10, z=-10..10)
```

You can also achieve a more visually-pleasing effect by increasing the number of grid points (the default is 10 by 10 by 10) and using *surface* style (the default is *surfacewireframe*).

```
implicitplot3d(x^2+y^2+z^2+2*x*y+2*x*y+2*y*z-x-y-z=6, x=-10..10, y=-10..10, z=-10..10,
grid=[20, 20, 20], style=surface)
```